# iPhone: Create sqlite database with foreign key supported

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am developing an iPhone application, where i need to store large data in an sqlite3 database.

I would like to create table with foreign key constraints for the below one example. How can i create the below tables using sqlite or programmatically?

Please advise!

```
"CREATE TABLE List (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ListId INTEGER UNIQUE, ListName TEXT, nameId INTEGER, FLAG BOOL)",
"CREATE TABLE User (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, ListId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(ListId) REFERENCES List(ListId))",
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use SQLite on the iPhone is to use a wrapper of the Sqlite C API, such as [fmdb](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

For example

```
NSString* databasePath = //path to where you want to store it on disk
FMDatabase* database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
[database open];
[self.database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE List (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ListId INTEGER UNIQUE, ListName TEXT, nameId INTEGER, FLAG BOOL)"];
[self.database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE User (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, ListId INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(ListId) REFERENCES List(ListId))"];
```

Although, using the low level sqlite library may be overkill. Something like [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdprogrammingguide.html) may be better depending on your situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I'm just going to just create, update, read the records. Is it possible to create db using sqlitemanager in firefox? But, i'm not seeing FOREIGN KEY in it.

Comment: If you want to create it in the firefox sqlite manager, just put those sql statements in the "Execute SQL" tab on the right side of the page.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! That should work properly right? If i add FOREIGN KEY in my query in "Execute SQL", that will also be shown there?

Comment: Yes all you need to do is put the foreign key in the CREATE TABLE statement. If the answer was helpful for you, consider pressing the accept button for it :-)